# 2010 jonway scooter won't start

Tags: starting, scooter

This scooter won't start when it gets wet when it rains what could be the problem? The undercarriage is not getting wet and the harness in the front is not getting wet and I don't have a clue where to look for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's the secondery ingnition system. It is getting damp and is missfiring at ether the coil. the wire or spark plug boot or even a cracked spark plug itself. The next dry night spray a fine mist of water at these componets when its running and you will see the high energey arc or spark at the point of High Kv leakage.